# How map data in object array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

LH and KR is my city name and I want a corresponding child array and I want loop through these child array how can I do?

```
{
  "LH": [
    "xyz",
    "CDE",
    "qwe"
  ],
  "KR": [
    "ABC",
    "xyz"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome! We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).   `cities["LH"].forEach((i, e) => console.log(e))`

Answer (score 0):

Just to print items under each city you can use following:

```
const cities = ['LH', 'KR'];
cities.forEach(item => console.log(...first[item]));
```

To iterate over inner array:

```
cities.forEach(item => first[item].forEach(innerItem => console.log(innerItem)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you'd like your resulting data to look like but here are a couple of options:

```js
const data = {
  "LH": [
    "xyz",
    "CDE",
    "qwe"
  ],
  "KR": [
    "ABC",
    "xyz"
  ]
}

const getResult = (city) => data[city].map(d => d)

console.log("Result for LH", getResult("LH"))
console.log("Result for KR", getResult("KR"))


// OR to get an array of both arrays:

const getDataForAllCities = Object.keys(data).map(city => data[city].map(d => d));

console.log(getDataForAllCities)
```